# Nested routes: How to query Rails DB and store values in JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need help troubleshooting a JQuery / Ajax request in a fitness-related Rails (4.1.8) application.  When a member selects an exercise from a drop-down menu, I want to dynamically show data from the last time he/she did the exercise.  To do this, I'm using JQuery / Ajax to fetch data from the database (Postgres 0.18.3).  I've already coded a working Ajax request, but I can't figure out how to dynamically change the ids in the url.  I want to store the ids in JavaScript variables to use in the urls for the Ajax requests.

I have the following nested routes:

```
resources :members do

        resources :strength_exercises
end
```

which gives me the following url for the sample workout record:

```
/members/1/strength_exercises/13
```

Here's the pertinent part of my working JavaScript / JQuery / Ajax code:

```
//Gets information about last strength exercise workout

        function getLastExercisePerformance() {     

            var member_id = 1;  //the logged in member

            var exercise_id = $("#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id").val(); //the exercise selected from drop-down menu       

            var workout_id = 13;  //the last workout that included the selected exercise

            var date_performed = $("#strength_date_perform");

        //  more variables here // 

                    $.ajax({  

                    dataType: "json",

                    url: "/members/"+member_id+"/strength_exercises/"+workout_id+".json",

                        success: function(data) {

                    date_performed.text(data.date_performed);

                // handling more response data here

                    }  // end callback

            })    // end ajax request

    }  //end getLastPerformance function
```

The JQuery dropdown menu change event:

```
// Gets data from last workout that included selected exercise

        $("#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id").change(function(){

        $(".your_last_strength_exercise").show();     

        getLastExercisePerformance();

    });  // end exercise change event
```

Everything works as expected when I hard-code the id values into the JavaScript / Ajax function.  The Ajax request succeeds:  all desired data is retrieved from the database and is properly presented in the Rails view.

Here are the results of my troubleshooting efforts to date ....

When I run the following query in the Rails console:

```
@last_strength_workout = StrengthExercise.where(strength_training_list_id: 64, member: 1).last
```

I retrieve the the data I want from the database:

```
 => #<StrengthExercise id: 13, sets: 3, reps: 15, weight: 310, date_performed: "2015-10-19", member_id: 1, created_at: "2015-11-24 20:29:20", updated_at: "2015-11-24 20:29:20", trainer_id: nil, muscle_group_id: 13, strength_training_list_id: 64, comment: "test", one_rep_max: 465.0, total_reps: 45>
```

When I type the following url into the browser:

http://localhost:3000//members/1/strength_exercises/13.json

It returns the the correct data in json format:
    "id":13,"member_id":1,"muscle_group_id":13,"strength_training_list_id":64,"sets":3,"reps":15,"total_reps":45,"weight":310,"one_rep_max":465.0,"date_performed":"2015-10-19","trainer_id":null,"created_at":"2015-11-24T12:29:20.668-08:00","updated_at":"2015-11-24T12:29:20.668-08:00","comment":"test"}

How do I dynamically pass the necessary ids into the Ajax url requests?  I appreciate any help and guidance about how to best accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content you wanna change around a div with id="content"

Pass the option selected.

```
$("#list_id").change(function(){
            var exercise_id = $('#list_id option:selected').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<%= get_workout_path %>",
                type: "GET",
                data: {"id" : exercise_id}
            });

});
```

controller

```
def get_workout
  @exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
  @workout = Workout.find(@exercise.workout.id)
end
```

get_workout.js.erb

```
$("#content").html("<%= j render 'content' %>");
```

_content.html.erb

```
content that you wanna change..
```

This's usually what I do.

Comment: Can't get your suggested solution to work. I changed the JQuery function, but no values are pulled from the database.  How do I structure the Ajax url? I'm not clear about how to implement your solution.  Please clarify your answer in the context of my posted Ajax code.  Thanks!

Comment: How about using the window.location.href ? I updated the answer.

Comment: the id I need to place in a variable or pass is not the id of the selected exercise(64).  I need to pass the id of the workout.  In my test example, the workout id is 13.  This workout (id -13 ) contains the foreign keys for the selected exercise (64) and logged in member (1).  I need to figure out how to pass the id of the workout (13).

Comment: I updated the answer with my way of handling ajax request. Let me know if there something wrong.

Comment: I will look at your approach to see if I can get it to work.  Will follow-up.

Comment: I'm still stumped on this one; unfortunately, I can't get your suggested solution to work for me. Getting name errors / no method errors. I'll continue researching how to dynamically pass the ids (of nested resources) to the Ajax request. Once I get that part figured out, my posted code works okay.  That's what makes coding fun. Thanks for your help.